# Help with smart contract

Tags: solidity

Hello i have these smart contracts:

```js
contract CarFactory {

    Car[] deployedCars;
 
    function createCar() public {
       Car newCar=new Car(this);
       deployedCars.push(newCar);  
     }

     function getDeployedCars() public view returns (Car[] memory) {
       return deployedCars;
     }

     function getDeployedCarsWhereTrue() public view returns (Car[] memory) {
       return deployedCars ///where bool made is true;
     }
}


contract Car {

      CarFactory  factory;

       bool made;
    
     constructor(CarFactory  _factory) {
       factory=_factory;
     }

      function makeTrue() {
       made=true;
     }

}
```

And i need the function getDeployedCarsWhereTrue to return only the addresses where the bool in the smart contract is true.Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check every element inside the array, I added the `getCount` function to be able to declare a size for the dynamic array:

```
 function getDeployedCarsWhereTrue() public view returns (Car[] memory) {
   uint count = getCount();
   Car[] memory result =  new Car[](count);;
   for(uint i = 0; i < deployedCars.length; i ++){
     if(deployedCars[i].made){
       result.push(deployedCars[i]);
     }
   }
   return result;
 }

function getCount() internal view returns (uint) {
  uint count;

  for (uint i = 0; i < deployedCars.length; i++) {
    if(deployedCars[i].made){
        count++;
    }
  }

  return count;
}
```

Neededless to say this is going to be very expensive in gas, I recommend having a separate array to save the made Cars.

Comment: thanks for your help .Yeah ik that this would be expensive but i wanted to see how it works.thx!